# Using func rank in SQLAlchemy to rank rows in a table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table defined like so:

```
   Column    |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
-------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id          | uuid    | not null  | plain   |              |
 user_id     | uuid    |           | plain   |              |
 area_id     | integer |           | plain   |              |
 vote_amount | integer |           | plain   |              |
```

I want to be able to generate a rank 'column' when I query this database. This rank column would be ordered by the `vote_amount` column. I have attempted to create a query to do this, it looks like so:

```
subq_rank = db.session.query(user_stories).add_columns(db.func.rank.over(partition_by=user_stories.user_id, order_by=user_stories.vote_amount).label('rank')).subquery('slr')
data = db.session.query(user_stories).select_entity_from(subq_rank).filter(user_stories.area_id == id).group_by(-subq_rank.c.rank).limit(50).all()
```

Hopefully my attempt will give you an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need in each query these columns better I would do it in DB. I would create a view which contains the column rank, and in the query I call this view to show directly the data in code:

```
CREATE VIEW [ranking_user_stories] AS
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM 
(SELECT *, rank() over (partition by user_stories.user_id order by user_stories.vote_amount ASC) AS ranking
FROM user_stories
WHERE user_stories.area_id = id) uS
ORDER BY vote_amount ASC
```

It's the same logic than your code but in SQL, if your are using MySQL, just change TOP 50 to LIMIT 50 (and put at the end of query). I don't see the sense to put the last group by by ranking, but if you need it:

```
CREATE VIEW [ranking_user_stories] AS
    SELECT TOP 50 MAX(id) AS id, user_id, area_id, MAX(vote_amount) AS vote_amount, ranking FROM 
    (SELECT *, rank() over (partition by user_stories.user_id order by user_stories.vote_amount ASC) AS ranking
    FROM user_stories
    WHERE user_stories.area_id = id) uS
    ORDER BY MAX(vote_amount) ASC
    GROUP BY user_id, area_id, ranking
```